# Firebase Auth - Activating SSO login methods for existing users only

Tags: firebase-authentication, single-sign-on

I'd like to implement SSO logins for users in my Firebase web app, but only for users that have an existing account. When I add e.g. the Microsoft provider in Firebase and implement the required UX flows in the web app, anyone with a Microsoft account is able to sign in using that, upon which a new user account is created (if they haven't signed in before). I'd like to restrict this to users that:

- have registered previously with e.g. an email and password login method, and
- have subsequently chosen to activate the SSO login method in the web app

Is there a recommended way to prevent the default behaviour in Firebase auth for SSO so that I can check for an existing account with the same email and its approved login methods before letting the user log in and/or create a new account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in Firebase Authentication, as it makes no distinction between sign-up and sign-in for OAuth users.

The typical approach to implement this is to create a list of the allowed users somewhere that both your app and your server-side logic can find it (like in one of Firebase's databases), and then check against this so-called allowlist in both your client-side and server-side application code (and security rules) after the user signs in and before executing any other application logic for them.

In the application itself, you could show this as "unable to sign in" to the user, since (despite you calling the Firebase API and signing them in there) they have not completed the sign-in into your application itself.